# Why is the constant term of $(1+x+y+xy)^n$ equal to $\frac{1}{2}\binom{2n}{n}$？

Tags: polynomials, induction, contest-math, noncommutative-algebra, group-rings

> If we define this: for any $x,y$ such that 
>   $x^2=y^2=1,xy\neq yx$, express in terms of $n$ the constant term of the expression $$f_{n}=(1+x+y+xy)^n\,.$$

I guess this result is $\dfrac{1}{2}\binom{2n}{n}$.

for $n=1$, we have
$f_{1}=1+x+y+xy$ the constant term is $1=\dfrac{1}{2}\binom{2}{1}$

for $n=2$, we have
$$f_{2}=(1+x+y+xy)(1+x+y+xy)=1+x+y+xy+x+x^2+xy+x^2y+y+yx+y^2+yxy+xy+xyx+xy^2+xyxy=1+x+y+xy+x+1+xy+y+y+yx+1+yxy+xy+xyx+x+xyxy=3+3x+3y+3xy+yx+yxy+xyx+xyxy$$ the term is $3=\dfrac{1}{2}\binom{4}{2}$

for $n=3$,we have $$f_{3}=f_{2}(1+x+y+xy)=(3+3x+3y+3xy+yx+yxy+xyx+xyxy)(1+x+y+xy)$$ the constant term is $$3+3x^2+3y^2+yxxy=3+3+3+yy=3+3+3+1=10=\dfrac{1}{2}\binom{6}{3}$$

I tink this problem very interesting,But maybe use induction to prove it?I can't it

Comment: I think this question interesting: such any $xy*xy=1,xyxxyx=1$ and so on

Comment: We are dealing with the group ring $\mathbb{Z}[C_2*C_2]$, where $C_2$ is the cyclic group of order $2$.   Maybe there are some interesting properties of this ring that may help.

Comment: Perhaps you'll be interested in the [noncommutative multinomial formula](https://www.jstor.org/stable/44239417).

Comment: I verified the claim to be true for $n=1,2,\ldots,10$ with a computer code.

Comment: @lhf Do you have a python compiler?  I can post the code (it will be hidden). I am not a good coder, so don't blame me for the slow performance, OK?

Comment: @lhf See my hidden answer.   You only have to modify the last two lines to get the range of $n$ you want.

Comment: @Batominovski, thanks a lot!

Comment: Is this $+$ comutative?

Comment: @Aqua  The existence of $1$ implies that addition is commutative.  Let $(R,+,\cdot)$ be a nearring with $1$ (we need only associativity of addition and multiplication, and the distribution laws hold).  This is because $$\begin{align}2a+2b&=2(a+b)=(1+1)(a+b)\\&=1(a+b)+1(a+b)\\&=a+b+a+b\,,\end{align}$$  for all $a$ and $b$ in $R$.  Thus, $a+b=b+a$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### **Inductive Proof**

We shall show that
$$f_n=(1+x)\,(xy)^{-(n-1)}\,(1+xy)^{2n-1}$$
for all positive integers $n$.  We start with
$$\begin{align}f_1&=1+x+y+xy=(1+xy)+(x+y)
\\&=(1+xy)+x\,(1+xy)=(1+x)\,(1+xy)
\\&=(1+x)\,(xy)^{-(1-1)}\,(1+xy)^{2\cdot 1-1}\,.\end{align}$$
Thus, the claim is true for $n=1$.  We now suppose that the claim holds for $n=k$ for some positive integer $k$.

By induction hypothesis,
$$\begin{align}f_{k+1}&=(1+x+y+xy)\,f_k\\&=(1+x+y+xy)\,(1+x)\,(xy)^{-(k-1)}\,(1+xy)^{2k-1}\,.\end{align}$$
We can see that
$$(1+x+y+xy)\,(1+x)\,(xy)^{-(k-1)}=(1+x)(1+y)(1+x)\,(xy)^{-(k-1)}\,.$$
Now,
$$(1+y)(1+x)=1+x+y+yx=(1+yx)+y(1+yx)=(1+y)(1+yx)\,,$$
so
$$\begin{align}(1+y)(1+x)\,(xy)^{-(k-1)}&=(1+y)(1+yx)\,(yx)^{k-1}\\&=(1+y)\,(yx)^{k-1}\,(1+yx)\\&=(1+y)\,(yx)^k\,(1+xy)\,.\end{align}$$
Therefore,
$$\begin{align}f_{k+1}&=(1+x)\,\big((1+y)\,(yx)^k\,(1+xy)\big)\,(1+xy)^{2k-1}\\&=(1+x)(1+y)\,(yx)^k\,(1+xy)^{2k}\,.\end{align}$$
However, as $(1+x)(1+y)=(1+x)(1+xy)$, we get
$$(1+x)(1+y)\,(yx)^k=(1+x)(1+xy)\,(yx)^k=(1+x)\,(yx)^k\,(1+xy)\,.$$
This shows that
$$\begin{align}
f_{k+1} &=\big((1+x)\,(yx)^k\,(1+xy)\big)\,(1+xy)^{2k}
\\
&=(1+x)\,(xy)^{-\big((k+1)-1\big)}\,(1+xy)^{2(k+1)-1}\,.
\end{align}$$
The proof is now complete.

Now, we have
$$\begin{align}f_n&=(1+x)\,(xy)^{-(n-1)}\,(1+xy)^{2n-1}\\&=(xy)^{-(n-1)}\,(1+xy)^{2n-1}+x\,(xy)^{-(n-1)}\,(1+xy)^{2n-1}\,.\end{align}$$ The constant term of $f_n$ can only come from the constant term of $(xy)^{-(n-1)}(1+xy)^{2n-1}$.  Therefore, the constant term of $f_n$ is
$$\binom{2n-1}{n-1}=\frac{1}{2}\,\binom{2n}{n}\,.$$
In fact, the coefficients of $(xy)^r$ and $x\,(xy)^r$ in $f_n$, where $r\in\mathbb{Z}$, are both equal to $$\displaystyle\binom{2n-1}{n-1+r}=\frac{n+r}{2n}\,\binom{2n}{n+r}\,.$$

---

### **Geometric Proof**

For $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$, let $\rho_\theta$ denote the counterclockwise rotation of the Euclidean plane $E:=\mathbb{R}^2$ by the angle $\theta$.  We also write $\sigma_\theta$ for the reflection about the line $\ell_\theta$ through the origin that makes the angle $\theta$ (measured in the counterclockwise direction) with the horizontal axis.  Define $\varpi_\theta$ to be the orthogonal projection onto $\ell_\theta$. 
 Note that 
$$\varpi_\theta=\frac{1+\sigma_\theta}{2}\,,$$ where $1$ also denotes the identity map on $E$.  We have some basic identities:
$$\rho_{\theta_1}\rho_{\theta_2}=\rho_{\theta_1+\theta_2}\,,$$
$$\sigma_{\theta_1}\sigma_{\theta_2}=\rho_{2\theta_1-2\theta_2}\,,$$
$$\sigma_{\theta_1}\rho_{\theta_2}=\sigma_{\theta_1-\frac{\theta_2}{2}}\,,$$
and
$$\rho_{\theta_1}\sigma_{\theta_2}=\sigma_{\frac{\theta_1}{2}+\theta_2}\,,$$
for all $\theta_1,\theta_2\in\mathbb{R}$.

Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be variable angles.  We consider $x:=\sigma_\alpha$ and $y:=\sigma_\beta$.  Then, $x^2=1$, $y^2=1$,
$$xy=\sigma_\alpha\sigma_\beta=\rho_{2\alpha-2\beta}\,,\text{ and }yx=\sigma_\beta\sigma_\alpha=\rho_{2\beta-2\alpha}\,.$$
It is easily verified that no two terms of the form $(xy)^r$ or $x\,(xy)^r$, where $r\in\mathbb{Z}$, are equal (as functions of $\alpha$ and $\beta$).

For a positive integer $n$, we perform an $n$-step transformation on the Euclidean plane $E$ such that, at each step, we can leave $E$ alone (this action, or rather, nonaction, corresponds to the identity $1$), reflect $E$ via the map $x$ or $y$, or rotate it via $xy$.  Let $T_n$ be the set of all possible $n$-step transformations.

We want to count all elements of $T_n$ that ending up leaving $E$ unchanged (that is, the composition of the successive maps performed at each step is the identity $1$).  Let this number be $q(n)$.  For each $\mathbf{t}\in T_n$, write $\tau_\mathbf{t}$ be the final mapping resulting from the $n$-step transformation $\mathbf{t}$.

Observe that, for all $v\in E$, we see that
$$\sum_{\mathbf{t}\in T_n}\,\tau_\mathbf{t}(v)=(1+x+y+xy)^n(v)=f_n(v)\,.$$
Now observe that
$$1+x+y+xy=(1+x)(1+y)=2^2\,\left(\frac{1+x}{2}\right)\,\left(\frac{1+y}{2}\right)\,.$$
Because 
$$\varpi_\alpha=\frac{1+x}{2}\text{ and }\varpi_\beta=\frac{1+y}{2}\,,$$
we conclude that $$f_n(v)=2^2\,(\varpi_\alpha\varpi_\beta)^n(v)\,.$$
Observe that
$$\varpi_\alpha\varpi_\beta\varpi_\alpha=\big(\cos(\alpha-\beta)\big)^2\,\varpi_\alpha\,.$$

By identifying $E$ with $\mathbb{C}^2$, we can write each $v$ as $r\,\text{e}^{\text{i}\phi}$ for some $r\geq 0$ and $\phi\in\mathbb{R}$.  Observe that
$$\varpi_\alpha\varpi_\beta(r\,\text{e}^{i\phi})=\cos(\alpha-\beta)\,\cos(\phi-\beta)\,\text{e}^{\text{i}\alpha}\,r\,.$$  This means
$$f_n(r\,\text{e}^{i\phi})=2^{2n}\,\big(\cos(\alpha-\beta)\big)^{2n-1}\,\cos(\phi-\beta)\,\text{e}^{\text{i}\alpha}\,r\,.$$
By writing 
$$\begin{align}\cos(\phi-\beta)&=\cos\big((\phi-\alpha)+(\alpha-\beta)\big)\\&=\cos(\phi-\alpha)\,\cos(\alpha-\beta)-\sin(\phi-\alpha)\,\sin(\alpha-\beta)\,,\end{align}$$
we obtain
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\,f_n(r\,\text{e}^{i\phi})\,\text{d}\beta=2^{2n}\,\left(\int_0^{2\pi}\,\cos^{2n}(\alpha-\beta)\,\text{d}\beta\right)\,\cos(\phi-\alpha)\,\text{e}^{\text{i}\alpha}\,r\,.$$
From [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/195488/solve-int-cos2n-theta-d-theta), we have
$$\begin{align}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\,f_n(r\,\text{e}^{i\phi})\,\text{d}\beta&=2^{2n}\,\frac{\pi}{2^{2n-1}}\,\binom{2n}{n}\,\cos(\phi-\alpha)\,\text{e}^{\text{i}\alpha}\,r\\&=2\pi\,\binom{2n}{n}\,\cos(\alpha-\phi)\,\text{e}^{\text{i}(\alpha-\phi)}\,r\,\text{e}^{\text{i}\phi}\,.\end{align}$$
Hence,
$$\begin{align}\int_0^{2\pi}\,\int_0^{2\pi}\,f_n(r\,\text{e}^{i\phi})\,\text{d}\beta\,\text{d}\alpha&=2\pi\,\binom{2n}{n}\,\left(\int_0^{2\pi}\,\cos(\alpha-\phi)\,\text{e}^{\text{i}(\alpha-\phi)}\,\text{d}\alpha\right)\,r\,\text{e}^{\text{i}\phi}\\&=2\pi^2\,\binom{2n}{n}\,r\,\text{e}^{\text{i}\phi}\,.\end{align}$$
That is,
$$\frac{1}{(2\pi)^2}\,\int_0^{2\pi}\,\int_0^{2\pi}\,f_n(r\,\text{e}^{i\phi})\,\text{d}\beta\,\text{d}\alpha=\frac{1}{2}\,\binom{2n}{n}\,r\,\text{e}^{\text{i}\phi}\,.$$

However, for each $\mathbf{t}\in T_n$,
$$\frac{1}{(2\pi)^2}\,\int_0^{2\pi}\,\int_0^{2\pi}\,\tau_\mathbf{t}(r\,\text{e}^{i\phi})\,\text{d}\beta\,\text{d}\alpha=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
r\,\text{e}^{i\phi}&\text{if }\tau_\mathbf{t}=1\,,\\
0&\text{if }\tau_\mathbf{t}\neq 1\,.
\end{array}\right.$$
Therefore,
$$\begin{align}\frac{1}{(2\pi)^2}\,\int_0^{2\pi}\,\int_0^{2\pi}\,f_n(r\,\text{e}^{i\phi})\,\text{d}\beta\,\text{d}\alpha&=\sum_{\mathbf{t}\in T_n}\,\frac{1}{(2\pi)^2}\,\int_0^{2\pi}\,\int_0^{2\pi}\,\tau_\mathbf{t}(r\,\text{e}^{i\phi})\,\text{d}\beta\,\text{d}\alpha\\&=q(n)\,r\,\text{e}^{\text{i}\phi}\,,\end{align}$$
Hence,
$$q(n)=\frac{1}{2}\,\binom{2n}{n}\,.$$

**Remark.**  Let $G$ be the group $\big\langle x,y\,\big|\,x^2=1\text{ and }y^2=1\big\rangle$.  Denote by $\mathcal{E}$ the $\mathbb{R}$-vector space of continuous maps $F:(\mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{Z})^2\to \text{End}_\mathbb{R}(E)$.  Basically, this approach uses the fact that the map $\Phi:G\to \text{GL}(\mathcal{E})$  given by 
$$\Big(\big(\Phi(x)\,F\big)(\alpha,\beta)\Big)\,u:=\sigma_\alpha \Big(F(\alpha,\beta)\,u\Big)$$
and
$$\Big(\big(\Phi(y)\,F\,\big)(\alpha,\beta)\Big)\,u:=\sigma_\beta \Big(F(\alpha,\beta)\,u\Big)\,,$$
where $\alpha,\beta\in \mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{Z}$, $F\in\mathcal{E}$, and $u\in E$,
is a faithful representation of $G$.

Comment: It's very very Nice!+1

Comment: FYI Your inductive proof can be greatly simplified by directly proving the stronger claim that you listed out at the end. Inducting on $n$, the term $(xy)^r$ is built by $ 1 \times (xy)^r$, $x \times y(xy)^{r-1}$, $y \times y(xy)^r$, $ xy times (xy)^{r-1}$.

Answer (score 23):

Let $R$ be algebra generated over $\mathbb{Z}$ by non-commuting variables $x$, $y$, subject to $x^2=y^2=1$. There is an algebra homomorphism $\varphi:R\to M_2(\mathbb{Z}[t,t^{-1}])$ given by
$$
x\mapsto \begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix},\hspace{10mm}y\mapsto \begin{bmatrix}0&t^{-1}\\t&0\end{bmatrix}.
$$
I claim that $\varphi$ is injective. To check this, note that there is a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis for $R$ consisting of $(xy)^n$ and $x(xy)^n$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, and observe that
$$
\varphi((xy)^n)=\begin{bmatrix}t^{n}&0\\0&t^{-n}\end{bmatrix},\hspace{10mm}\varphi(x(xy)^n)=\begin{bmatrix}0&t^{-n}\\t^{n}&0\end{bmatrix}
$$
are $\mathbb{Z}$-linearly independent.

Now, we have
$$
\varphi(1+x+y+xy)=\begin{bmatrix}1+t&1+t^{-1}\\1+t&1+t^{-1}\end{bmatrix}=(1+t)\begin{bmatrix}1&t^{-1}\\1&t^{-1}\end{bmatrix}.
$$
It is easy to check by induction that
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1&t^{-1}\\1&t^{-1}\end{bmatrix}^n = (1+t^{-1})^{n-1}\begin{bmatrix}1&t^{-1}\\1&t^{-1}\end{bmatrix},
$$
so we get
$$
\varphi\big((1+x+y+xy)^n\big)=(1+t)^n (1+t^{-1})^{n-1}\begin{bmatrix}1&t^{-1}\\1&t^{-1}\end{bmatrix}=t^{-n+1}(1+t)^{2n-1}\begin{bmatrix}1&t^{-1}\\1&t^{-1}\end{bmatrix}.
$$
The constant coefficient of $(1+x+y+xy)^n$ is the coefficient of $1$ in the upper left entry of the matrix above, which is
$$
{2n-1\choose n-1}=\frac{1}{2}{2n\choose n}.
$$

Comment: +1  Thank for your nice answer,This is the Olympic competition question (for middle school students),so maybe have other without matrix methods?such as sequence? Thanks