# Mistake on the reduction formula for $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^{2n}{(x)}\,dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, reduction-formula

I've found online that $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^{2n}{(x)}\,dx = \frac{\pi}{2^{2n-1}} \binom{2n}{n}$. I've tried it on my own and I've got $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^{2n}{x}\,dx = \frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}} \frac{(2n-1)!!}{n!}$, where the double factorial is the product of all odd numbers from $1$ up to $2n-1$.

To compute the integral, I've integrated by parts splitting $\cos^{2n}{(x)}$ in $\cos^{2n-1}{(x)}$ and $\cos{(x)}$, then iterating, obtaining the following:

$I_n = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^{2n}{(x)}\,dx = (2n-1)\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(\cos^{2n-2}{(x)} - \cos^{2n}{(x)})\,dx = (2n-1)(I_{n-1} - I_n)$

$\Rightarrow I_n = \frac{2n-1}{2n}I_{n-1} \Rightarrow I_n = \frac{(2n-1)!!}{2^n n!} I_0 = \frac{(2n-1)!!}{2^n n!} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\,dx = \frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}} \frac{(2n-1)!!}{n!}$

Unfortunately for me, this formula is wrong, but I can't quite figure out where I'm going wrong.

Could somebody please help me find the mistake?

Answer (score 2):

Note that
\begin{align}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^{2n}{x}\,dx =&\ \frac{\pi}{2^{2n+1}} \binom{2n}{n}
=\frac{\pi}{2^{2n+1}} \frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}\\
=&\ \frac{\pi}{2^{2n+1}} \frac{(2n)!!(2n-1)!!}{(n!)^2}
=\frac{\pi}{2^{2n+1}} \frac{2^n n!(2n-1)!!}{(n!)^2}\\
=&\ \frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}} \frac{(2n-1)!!}{n!}
\end{align}
So, your result is correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this super-quick answer! I guess I've just messed up something with the calculator then lol

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you cited the [online source](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2106791/463578) incorrectly by a factor of $4$. In fact, the source states your integral
$$I = \int_0^{\pi/2} \cos^{2n}x dx = \frac{\pi}{2^{2n+1}}\binom{2n}{n}=:(\ast)$$

But this is the same as your calculation as $(2n-1)!!(2n)!!=(2n)!$ so $(2n-1)!!=\frac{(2n)!}{2^nn!}$, and thus your calculation

$$=\frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}\frac{(2n-1)!!}{n!}=\frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}2^n}\frac{(2n)!}{n!n!}=(\ast)=I.$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I think I misread a $2\pi$ for a $\frac{\pi}{2}$